# PoE standard supported on Cisco WS-C3524-PWR-XL switch

Tags: power-over-ethernet

What is the PoE standard supported on Cisco WS-C3524-PWR-XL switch? Only the ILP? `show power` does not provide any useful information in that regard and under interfaces configuration it allows one to configure `inline power`:

```
C3524(config-if)#power inline ?
  auto   Automatically detect and power inline devices
  never  Never apply inline power

C3524(config-if)#power inline
```

Last but not least, am I correct that *IEEE 802.3af* capable devices do not work with ILP equipment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Cisco support forum](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10478581/ws-c3524-pwr-xl-support-8023af) seems to indicate that this switch is pre-standard and therefore doesn't support AF or AT.

Answer (score 1):

This switch went end of sales in Aug 2003 and the af spec wasn't fully ratified until 2003. So it's most likely pre af standard which Cisco supported based on af drafts. I've never had a problem with the pre AF Cisco devices not working. Will work fine with most inline power products with Caveats.

Show power doesn't have anything to do with show power inline, two different areas of the switch. If you are wanting the most trouble free setting then enter power inline auto. Will auto negotiate the power level to a max of 15.4w per port up to a max 325w on a 24 port model. From experience if you are doing this specifically for VoIP phones you can run into problems depending on the IOS. Newer ip phones will want LLDP-MED TLV extension protocol support which won't be in a switch this old. At best the switch will have CDP TLV but possibly not the TLV needed. On some models you can manually build the CDP-TLV list and save. That's before you end get to weak QoS support in switch for phones. If you are just doing dumb devices like PoE IP security cameras then the switch will work just fine. Will end up around 6.8w per camera.